# how to access a range of public IPs only through a VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip, routing, pptp, pf

For security reasons, I am not supposed to access an otherwise public IP range unless a VPN is up. However, if my VPN is down, my system routes to the IP anyway, which is a breach of my obligations. Could I somehow restrict my own system to drop attempts at connecting to that IP range if it cannot route through the VPN?

I am using Mac OS Mavericks.

I can play around with some settings of the PF firewall, via the IceFloor front end. But I would need some help what is the best way to approach this, what rule, etc. (E.g. I hope I don't need a virtual adapter for this, they haven't been very flexible or stable.)

I could also set up rules using etc/ppp/ip-up and etc/ppp/ip-down for routing when the VPN is up, but exactly the reason why I need to shut it down when the VPN is down was that there was nothing to route to when there was no VPN alive. So what is there to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be straightforward to set up PF rules that always reject anything going to that IP range on the physical interface. The VPN's virtual interface, when present, wouldn't match, and the physical interface would not see the real target (because it'd be encapsulated by the VPN software, and part of the payload of the "physical" packet).

The PF rule would look something like `block out quick on en0 to 192.168.210.0/24` (specifying the correct network, of course; I have never seen IceFloor, so can't suggest how to use that).